# problems diagnosing time spent in a for loop C#

Tags: c#, database, for-loop, timer, timing

I have a for loop that is taking way too long and i dont know why.

```
Stopwatch proctime = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch innerlooptime = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch outerlooptime = new Stopwatch();

proctime.Start();
int length = inbtable.Rows.Count;
outerlooptime.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    outerlooptime.Stop();
    DataRow newrow = graphdata.NewRow();
    innerlooptime.Start();
    for (int j = 0; j < graphdata.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        colname = graphdata.Columns[j].ColumnName;
        newrow[j] = inbtable.Rows[i][colname];
    }
    innerlooptime.Stop();
    outerlooptime.Start();
    graphdata.Rows.Add(newrow);
}
proctime.Stop();
```

if you time it all out, the time spent on just the "inner loop" or the j-loop is like 1/10th of a second.

the time spent inside the i loop, but not the j-loop is like 1/10th of a second.

the time spent on the total loop is around 1-second. so Time-iloop + Time-jloop is like 1/5th of the total time. where is the rest of the time being spent? take a look at the image, comparing processing time (proctime in the code), outerloop time and innerloop time. why dont those add up to something much closer to each other?

[image]

Comment: you start outerlooptime outside the first loop but stop it as soon as the loop starts?

Comment: If you're using visual studio, try running the performance profiler with microsoft symbols enabled (options -> debugging -> symbols).  The "hotpath" produced by a cpu profile should indicate which calls are taking up the most time.

Comment: James, that sounds like exactly what i need. Thanks! Im going to try it right now

Comment: Alex, i am trying to account for all the time, so that includes the declaration of the int i on the first go. after the j-loop, the outerloop timer starts again to account for the time spent on i++ and the i< length logic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the declarations of your timers, but the variable names imply that you are looking at the processor time, not the actual amount of time spend.  Processor time is the amount of time spent by the processor core running your calculations - the processor is shared among all the processes running on your computer, so in 1 second, it is perfectly reasonable to receive 0.2 seconds of processor time.

Try using the Stopwatch class instead:

```
// using System.Diagnostics;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

DoThings(); // run your code

sw.Stop();
Debug.WriteLine("Actual time elapsed: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

Comment: They are actually stopwatches, i labeled proctime as processing time for the loop.

Comment: Sorry, bad assumption on my part.  Maybe `DataRow newrow = graphdata.NewRow();` is taking up a lot of time - it doesn't seem to be counted in either loop.  The time spent instantiating objects is not negligible...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. it was really silly. i had the stopwatches switched around in my message box statement at the end of the function, so one stopwatch was being reported as another one. all the time is being spent somewhere else, outside the code i posted. Thanks for all of your help.